# How to get username from Facebook SDK 4.0 in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

How to get **username** from facebook sdk 4.0 in iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can´t get the username anymore:

> /me/username is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

If you want to detect returning users, use the (App Scoped) ID instead.

Answer (score 9):

```
-(IBAction)LoginWithFacebook:(id)sender {

    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

        [self getDetailsAndLogin];

    }
    else{
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Process error
                NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                // Handle cancellations
                NSLog(@"Result Cancelled!");
            } else {
                // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                // should check if specific permissions missing

                if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                    // Do work
                    [self getDetailsAndLogin];

                }
            }
        }];

    }

}

-(void)getDetailsAndLogin{
    if (LOGGING) {
        return;
    }
    LOGGING = YES;
    [super startLoader];
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSString *userID = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] userID];
             NSString *userName = [result valueForKey:@"name"];
             NSString *email =  [result valueForKey:@"email"];
             NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] userID]];

             [User LoginWithFbId:userID Username:userName Email:email ImageUrl:userImageURL success:^(User *response) {
                 [super stopLoader];
                 UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                 TabViewController *TabVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabViewController"];
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:TabVC animated:YES];

             } failure:^(NSString *error) {
                 LOGGING = NO;
                 [super stopLoader];
                 [super showAlertWithTitle:@"Cannot Login" Message:error];
             }];
         }
         else{
             LOGGING = NO;
             [super stopLoader];
             NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
         }
     }];

}
```

here `LoginWithFacebook` is a button action to get data . Do not forget to import SDK of FBSession which you can get easily from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) . Register your app create a key and import this key in your application.
Happy coding

Answer (score 4):

Easiest Answer would be to check the following after user is logged in:

```
if ([FBSDKProfile currentProfile]) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"User name: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].name);
    NSLog(@"User ID: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID);
}
```

Comment: This may not necessarily be safe (as I have learnt the hard way). currentProfile has sometimes not finished being fetched  even if currentAccessToken is not null. in this case you may get a null profile.

Comment: if ([FBSDKProfile currentProfile]) {
        NSLog(@"User name: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].name);
        NSLog(@"User ID: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID);
        
    }

add this checking to avoid null

Answer (score 2):

*Use my code its works excellent.

```
- (IBAction)tapon_facebookLogin:(id)sender {
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    // TODO:Token is already available.
       NSLog(@"FBSDKAccessToken alreay exist");
       [self fetchFbUserInfo];

}else{
    NSLog(@"FBSDKAccessToken not exist");
    FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"]
                        fromViewController:self
                                   handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                       //TODO: process error or result
                                       if (!error) {
                                           NSLog(@"result %@",result.debugDescription);
                                           [self fetchFbUserInfo];
                                       }else{
                                           NSLog(@"errorfacebook %@",error.description);
                                       }
                                   }];
}}




-(void)fetchFbUserInfo{

if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
{
    NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"resultisfetchFbUserInfo:%@",result);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"ErrorfetchFbUserInfo %@",error);
         }
     }];}}
```

Comment: Excellent indeed!